# Finding Circles that contain specific Point

Tags: performance, database-design

I've got a database of many `circles` (each has x,y and radius).
I need to find each circle that includes a specific point given by x/y.

Is there a way to do this in `better than linear time`? 
Testing each circle slows down my application quiet much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a matter of properly index (eg.sort) your "database". The problem is that while you may sort per axis (x or y), then radius could vary. There may be a lot of way to return your result, but i think you cannot beat a linear-time approach.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of geometric indexing, in some RDBMS you could create function-based indexes for:

```
x-r
x+r
y-r
y+r
```

... and add predicates to your query for:

```
select ...
where  point_x between x-r and x+r and
       point_y between y-r and y+r and
       ... etc ...
```

It would at least get you candidate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have managed to sort the circles in a very specific order, I don't see how this could be done faster than linear time.

There may be some good optimization left to do if you provide us with your query though.